# Difference between Adobe Flex and HTML 5

Tags: apache-flex, html

I hear that HTML 5 is also useful for developing Rich Internet Applications. Can anyone please explain the difference between the Adobe Flex and HTML5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain the difference between the Adobe Flex and
>   HTML5.

Big question.  Adobe Flex is an SDK (Software Development Kit) that includes a User Interface Framework, a command line compiler and other tools.  The output of an Adobe Flex application is either a SWF, which runs in the browser based Flash Player, or an AIR file which will run in conjunction with Adobe's desktop runtime.

Flex is part of Adobe's Flash Platform.  I'm going to [quote myself](http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2011/11/21/In-Defense-of-Flash) to explain what the Flash Platform is:

> The Flash Platform consists of multiple deployment runtimes, development tools, and frameworks that are integrated across the full
>   Adobe Creative Suite. Here is a list of some Flash Platform elements:
>
> > 1. The Flash Player: Flash Player is a browser plug-in which allows us
> >        to deploy web based applications to Windows, Mac, Linux, Android,
> >        and Blackberry.
> > 2. Adobe AIR: Adobe AIR is a runtime that allows us to deploy native
> >            applications to Windows, Mac, Android, iOS, and Blackberry.
> > 3. Flash Professional: Flash Professional is a tool for developing
> >        timeline based animations.
> > 4. Flash Builder: Flash Builder is an IDE to help programmer's write
> >        advanced code.
> > 5. Adobe Flex: Flex is the Software Development Kit that helps
> >        programmers build, debug, and deploy Enterprise applications with
> >        the Flash Platform. Flex includes a UI Component library, a SWF
> >        compiler, a command line debugger, an application profiler.
>
> There are more aspects of the Flash Platform ecosystem, but I
>   highlight these because they come from Adobe and are prominently used
>   by Flash Platform developers.

HTML5 is a spec for the next version of HTML.  HTML is a markup language for building web pages.  It includes some new aspects for dealing with video (Video Tag) and for creating animations (Canvas).

HTML5, alone, is not a good choice for building Applications.

However, when most people talk about HTML5 they also lump in JavaScript--which is a language used primarily for modifying a web browser's Document Object Model--and CSS3 which provides advanced styling support for HTML5 elements.  HTML5, combined with JavaScript and CSS3 can be a good choice for building the UI for a browser based mobile web application.  HTML5 support on mobile devices is very consistent because the major mobile OSes (Android and iOS) use the same rendering engine (WebKit)  in their respective browsers.

On the desktop, more web rendering engines exist, and many people have older versions of the browser.  Building an appplication, targeted for the desktop, with HTML5 technologies is not a decision I would make lightly, but it depends primarily on your audience.

Answer (score -5):

HTML5 is a developing standard which already has significant adoption and holds significant promise.

flex is proprietary and requires a plugin to work and its prognosis is dim -- adobe has already discontinued the development of the mobile plugin.

apple does not support flex.

Comment: :- Thanks for quick response. I want to develop mobile application using HTML 5. So which IDE can use for developing it.

Comment: "Apple does not support flex" is incorrect.  Devices running iOS don't support the flash player - however they can still run applications built in Flex.  Flex can be used to build mobile applications, compiled to AIR, which run on almost all mobile platforms - including All iOS (iPad, iPod, etc).

Comment: whatever, the succinct characterization is good enough for the purpose of the question. if you're feeling pedantic, go invest in a thorough answer of your own @marty

Comment: @ravi, not familiar with IDE's, it would be a good new question or a search

Comment: @ravi you can use your favourite text editor to write html, but "html5" will not magically give you a mobile application. You are going to need some help from libraries like phonegap & jquery mobile.

Comment: @agksmehx If being accurate is pedantic, then guilty as charged.  No need to write a response to this question, Flextra's has already provided an answer which is thorough, factual and accurate.

Comment: adobe stoped only flash player for different browsers in the mobile. Flash swf file can open independtly in mobile os.